# Internet synchronization for Access 2000 using Windows Server 2008 and IIS 7.5

Tags: ms-access, windows-server-2008, replication

I am using Access2000 and Developer Tools, JRO for internet synch, RepMan 4, and was using Win Server 2003 (dedicated server).  Just upgraded to Win Server 2008 and have been trying to get Internet synch operational, but with no luck.  Here's my problem:  I see that MS is urging/forcing subscriptions to SharePoint2010 for internet synchs, however I am not sure that their new platform is as useful to me as their old.  Each company I distribute to will run a runtime version of my access application at multiple locations(could be 1 location per company, could be 100).  They need to be able to direct synch within each location via LAN (anywhere from 2 to 20 computers).  They do not always have an Internet connection (they are at sea), and when they do, it's by satellite and transmission costs are high.  And so occasionally they will connect with one computer and perform Internet Replication to send data to home office(could be daily, weekly, or monthly).  My current  means of synching via JRO is very simple.  After attaining an Internet connection, just open a form and either click the synch LAN button or the synch Internet button.  Also, by not utilizing automatic synchs, we avoid corrupting other replicas when one is bad or a user has deleted massive amounts of data inadvertently (since deletes always win).

I feel that eventually I will have to update to Access2010 just to keep abreast on new developments in MS (i.e. new .PDF reports instead of .SNP).  I recently purchased Office 2010 Pro in order to begin looking into this, but of course this will take some time to work thru.

Here are my questions:

1. Will SharePoint2010 allow for only one subscription per remote location to handle synchronization back to main office, or would every replica that performs a direct synch at the remote office be required to maintain a Sharepoint2010 subscription?
2. Can I still use JRO to complete direct synchs among replicas at a remote location and within the home office, and therefore only use Sharepoint 2010 to pass those updates via Internet to the home office.
3. Will Sharepoint 2010 Enterprise allow me to host multiple company databases in one central account (similar to RepMan4), or must I set up a separate account for each of my customers?  If so, do I need to purchase a copy of Sharepoint 2010 for each of these customers?
4. Will Sharepoint 2010 handle basic data replication and/or design updates in a similar manner to my current set-up?  Will I be able to utilize my custom conflict manager?
5. Also- do you have any info whether Internet synchronizations are indeed capable utilizing Access2000 viaIIS 7.5 on Windows Server 2008 with RepMan4?  I have not found anyone who has accomplished this – latest suggestion is that maybe IIS needs to be run in a 32-bit environment in order to open the synchronizer, but I have not yet tried this.

Answer (score 0):

My company makes a product called [EQL OnWeb - **link deleted**] which is designed for exactly your use case.  It works with getting Access 2000 databases on the web without rewriting them first, and there's a free trial so you can see if you like it.

I won't comment in detail on SharePoint 2010 because clearly I'm biased... but I like our product better :)

Comment: In case you haven't noticed, this answer is being flagged as spam, and it does look a little spammy, but I'm not sure if it really was meant like that, so you might want to amend it to make it more clear in what way you're answering the question.

Comment: I think it's a valid suggestion - the questioner doesn't seem to actually want to upgrade to SharePoint at all.  But let's leave it to the voters to decide; that's the point.

Comment: Regardless of whether it's spam or not (I'd say it's not), it's actually not really a valid answer. It doesn't address the underlying problem of synching data between multiple locations, and offline versus online use.